# Jquery Mobile: 'pageshow' event fired only at Shift F5(full reload), but not fired when loading another page or same page with different query

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile

This is schema of my `page.html`:

```html
<head>
    <script... jquery
    <script... jquery.mobile
    <scripts... imagemapster, autocomplete, etc...
</head>
<body>
    <div page1..
    </div>
    <div page2..
    </div>
    <my script with functions and initializations...
</body>
```

In my `<script>`, there's some bindings to `page1.pageshow` event. When I load the whole page directly, ensuring that all scripts were loaded first time, my script also loads correctly and works without any flaw. Even when going from `page2` back to `page1`, event is fired.

BUT, when I go to another page, or refresh the same page with JM built-in ajax functions, either my script is not loaded, or `pageshow` on `page1` is not fired.

I tried putting the script in the end of `page1`, or into head, but it's still not working on reload. I also cannot place it before any div involved (there's some events attached to many tags in all pages) - because not only `pageshow` missed, but also `ready` and `pageload`.

Sorry for I cannot show the whole code, but which way you would work and seek to find out what is the problem?

Comment: Try out [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZVypq/7/) to find out how to use the *pageshow* event properly.

Comment: Is it a single page app (html file, not jqm pages), or you navigate to `page.html` from another html page?

Comment: how did you do your bindings to `pageshow`? Using `.bind()` or `.on()`? I experienced issues using `.bind()`. Note that `.on()` is working much better.

Comment: When you say '...when I go to another page...' you mean you go a page that is defined outside `page.html` and when you go back your problem occurs. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Your script here, will be fired only once which is at document load

```
<head>
    <script... jquery
    <script... jquery.mobile
    <scripts... imagemapster, autocomplete, etc...
</head>
<body>
    <div page1..
      <script with the (page1).on(pageshow event handler)>
    </div>
    <div page2..
      <script with the (page2).on(pageshow event handler)>
    </div>
    <script here fired only once at document load>
</body>
```

You are terribly mistaken to expect that it will always be fired every transition of page since you are using one page to include all actual pages.
Normally, each page script is coded inside the div[data-role=page].
Make sure you are using the page id as selector for each inline pageshow event handler.

Comment: @user1475428 whether you use .bind and .on in your issue, it doesnt matter, cause it is not the root cause of your issue